# How to add CarbonInterval instance in Carbon instance

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a carbon instance

```
   $a = Carbon\Carbon::now();

   Carbon\Carbon {
     "date": "2018-06-11 10:00:00",
     "timezone_type": 3,
     "timezone": "Europe/Vienna",
   }
```

and a CarbonInterval instance

```
   $b = CarbonInterval::make('1month');


     Carbon\CarbonInterval {
     "y": 0,
     "m": 1,
     "d": 0,
     "h": 0,
     "i": 0,
     "s": 0,
     "f": 0.0,
     "weekday": 0,
     "weekday_behavior": 0,
     "first_last_day_of": 0,
     "invert": 0,
     "days": false,
     "special_type": 0,
     "special_amount": 0,
     "have_weekday_relative": 0,
     "have_special_relative": 0,
   }
```

How to add the interval in the carbon instance so that I would get

```
   Carbon\Carbon {
     "date": "2018-07-11 10:00:00",
     "timezone_type": 3,
     "timezone": "Europe/Vienna",
   }
```

I am aware of solution that involve converting it to timestamp or Datetime class like this

```
strtotime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 month", $a->timestamp ) ) );
```

which is what currently I am using but I am looking for a more "carbony" way I searched through the [official site](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) but couldn't find anything on this so need some help.

Update:
Just to give you the context
On frontend I have two controls 1st is for interval (days,months,year) 2nd is a text box so depending on the combination I generate strings dynamically like "`2` `days`" , "`3` `months`" so on that then gets feed to interval classes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built-in function to add an interval, but what should work is adding the total seconds of an interval to the date:

```
$date = Carbon::now(); // 2018-06-11 17:54:34
$interval = CarbonInterval::make('1hour');

$laterThisDay = $date->addSeconds($interval->totalSeconds); // 2018-06-11 18:54:34
```

---

**Edit: Found an easier way!**

```
$date = Carbon::now(); // 2018-06-11 17:54:34
$interval = CarbonInterval::make('1hour');

$laterThisDay = $date->add($interval); // 2018-06-11 18:54:34
```

This works because `Carbon` is based on `DateTime` and `CarbonInterval` is based on `DateInterval`. See [here](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.add.php) for method reference.

Answer (score 2):

See documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

```
$carbon = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$monthLater = clone $carbon;
$monthLater->addMonth(1);
dd($carbon, $monthLater);
```

result is

```
Carbon {#416 ▼
  +"date": "2018-06-11 16:00:48.127648"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}

Carbon {#418 ▼
  +"date": "2018-07-11 16:00:48.127648"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

For this interval [months, centuries, years, quarters, days, weekdays, weeks, hours, minutes, seconds], type you can use

```
$count = 1; // for example
$intrvalType = 'months'; // for example
$addInterval = 'add' . ucfirst($intrvalType);
$subInterval = 'sub' . ucfirst($intrvalType);
$carbon = Carbon\Carbon::now();
dd($carbon->{$addInterval}($count));
dd($carbon->{$subInterval}($count));
```

Comment: Thanx but I am generating the interval dynamically. If I go by this I would need a lot of if else for every case (days, month etc) which is what I am trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Can you your dynamic part of code convert to string??

Comment: If you can you can use this code **$carbon->addSeconds(1);**

Comment: `CarbonInterval::make('{$count}{$interval}');` here these two variables come from user, depending on which it generates appropriate interval like for example strings like `$count=2` and `$interval = 'days'` gives `2days`;  or another example `$count=3` and `$interval = 'months'` gives "3months" which you then feed to CarbonInterval to get interval of 3 months

Comment: @Viney see my updated answer how you can do using my suggested method

Comment: Yea this is nice alternative solution.