# -loop, is there easier way to do with carbon?

Tags: for-loop, laravel-5.7

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and carbon 1.x.

I need to build dateLooper which interval is 5 days and follows calender dates.

I need to find the way build looper which add 5 days for startdate.

ex.

```
   $startDate = "2014-01-01";
   $interval  = "5";
```

so     $endDate   =  $startDate + 5 ;

so    endDates 2014-01-05
               2014-01-10
      till     2014-01-30, so this is tricky because need to follow calender.
Next           2014-02-04.

I was reading Carbon but did not find any examples
which could have open solution for my problem.

And I realized that L5.7 is still using 1.x carbon.

I have tried to build double for-loop, but did not work
as it stops after reach end of inside loop.

```
  $month ="13" ;   // +1;
  $day ="29" ;   // +1;


 for ($i = 1; $i < $month; $i++)
 {
  echo "Month: ".$i.'<br/>';

    for ($i = 1; $i < $day; $i++)
    {
      echo "Day: ".$i.'<br/>';
    }
  }
```

1) So is there way to do with Carbon?
   or is there some other library which I could use? Ideas..

Thanks MikroMike.

Answer (score 0):

I found it from [How to add CarbonInterval instance in Carbon instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801192/how-to-add-carboninterval-instance-in-carbon-instance)

```
$carbon = Carbon::now();
$monthLater = clone $carbon;
$monthLater->addDay(15);
dd($carbon, $monthLater);
```

This has resolved my issue.